# Gitlab CI ParameterResolutionException Failed to resolve parameter

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, selenium-jupiter

I have test case that works fine in my local eclipse environment.

```
@Test
@Order(1)
void testTitle(@Arguments("--headless") ChromeDriver driver) {
    driver.get("https://google.com");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    assertThat(driver.getTitle(), containsString("Google"));
}
```

But when I used the same in Gitlab it fails. I used the following docker image: maven:3.3.9-jdk-8.

It downloads and extracts chrome driver
https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/90.0.4430.24/chromedriver_linux64.zip
*2021-05-17 16:33:54.508  INFO   --- [           main] i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.online.Downloader     : Downloading https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/90.0.4430.24/chromedriver_linux64.zip
2021-05-17 16:33:54.977  INFO   --- [           main] i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.online.Downloader     : Extracting driver from compressed file chromedriver_linux64.zip
2021-05-17 16:33:55.083  INFO   --- [           main] i.g.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager      : Exporting webdriver.chrome.driver as /root/.cache/selenium/chromedriver/linux64/90.0.4430.24/chromedriver*

but shows the following error during test execution

Caused by: io.github.bonigarcia.seljup.SeleniumJupiterException:
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

Any idea from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue and resolved it. Needed to use another docker image maven-chrome.